# RecyclerView Multiple ViewHolders ItemDetailsLookup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview (for chatview) loads views correctly but when I tap a view it throws cast exception:

```
ViewHolderReceived cannot be cast to ViewHolderSent
```

**ViewHolders:**

```
class ViewHolderReceived(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
                override fun inSelectionHotspot(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
            }

        fun bind(isSelected: Boolean = false) {
            itemView.isSelected = isSelected
        }
    }

    //#########################################################################

    class ViewHolderSent(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
                override fun inSelectionHotspot(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
            }

        fun bind(isSelected: Boolean = false) {
            itemView.isSelected = isSelected
        }
    }
```

**ItemDetailsLookup:**

```
class MyItemDetailsLookup(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) :
    ItemDetailsLookup<Long>() {
    override fun getItemDetails(event: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<Long>? {
        val view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)
        if (view != null) {
            return if(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0){
                (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderReceived)
                    .getItemDetails()} else {
                (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderSent)
                    .getItemDetails()} // error here
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

No matter which view is tapped, it throws same error (for ViewHolderReceived or  ViewHolderSent) but binds them correctly in correct order.

**Note:** It only throws error if I tap received view after tapping any of sent views or vice versa

**Found Solution:** The problem was recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(silly me, wrote it half asleep).

Comment: why are you checking `getChildAdapterPosition`?

Comment: view full error text

Comment: Because it has to be casted to either received or sent viewholders, by default it is recyclerview.viewholder which doesn't contain definations for getItemDetails @Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily solved if you extracted shared method up to super class or interface, then you'll be able to perform a safe cast regardless. For example:

```
abstract class SelectableViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
        object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
            override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
            override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
            override fun inSelectionHotspot(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                return true
        }
    }

    open fun bind(isSelected: Boolean = false) {
        itemView.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

class ViewHolderReceived(view: View) : SelectableViewHolder(view) {
    override fun bind(isSelected: Boolean = false) {
        super.bind(isSelected)
        // anything else specific for received viewholder
    }
}

class ViewHolderSent(view: View) : SelectableViewHolder(view) {
    override fun bind(isSelected: Boolean = false) {
        super.bind(isSelected)
        // anything else specific for sent viewholder
    }
}
```

Then lookup is easy:

```
class MyItemDetailsLookup(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) : ItemDetailsLookup<Long>() {
    override fun getItemDetails(event: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<Long>? {
        return recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)?.let {
            (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(it) as SelectableViewHolder).getItemDetails()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164201/android-recyclerview-how-to-handle-viewholder-with-multiple-bindings

Answer (score 0):

```
return if(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0){
            (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderReceived)
                .getItemDetails()} else {
            (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderSent)
                .getItemDetails()} // error here
```

You're assuming that the position is for sure returning a value that you're casting to. When you do `SomeValue as SomeType` you are making the assertion that `SomeValue` is for sure an inheritor of `SomeType`.

If you don't know that that's the case, which in this case you don't since you have two possible types you can cast to. You have to check if a type `is` of a certain type before you cast it.

If it's not, you'll get the error that you're getting `cannot cast x to y`

you should gate the calls with

```
if(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0){
    if (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) is MyAdapter.ViewHolderReceived) {
        (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderReceived).getItemDetails()
    } else {
        (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MyAdapter.ViewHolderSent).getItemDetails()
        (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view).getItemDetails
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it can be improved but the problem itself was wrong as i was checking if adapterPositon for view was 0.