# Android - RecyclerView how to handle ViewHolder with multiple bindings

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

Here is my onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MessageModel message = values.get(position);
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO_SENT:
                ((VideoMessageHolder) holder).sentBinding.setMessageModel(message);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO_RECEIVED:
                ((VideoMessageHolder) holder).receivedBinding.setMessageModel(message);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is my ViewHolder:

```
    private class VideoMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageSentBinding sentBinding;
        private RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageReceivedBinding receivedBinding;

        VideoMessageHolder(RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageSentBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.sentBinding = binding;
        }

        VideoMessageHolder(RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageReceivedBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.receivedBinding = binding;
        }

    }
```

I want to be able to get appropriate binding to be able to make changes to the views inside.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CKmDNMjYZV/

Comment: Can you explain specifically what you need? Does this code build? Does the app crash? Say what's happening vs what you want to happen, etc.

Comment: As I have two separate layouts for each video message (one is left oriented and the other is right in chat, nothing else is different) I want to be able to, for example, make changes to the views the changes will be same regardless of rcvd view holder or sent view holder, So I don't want create separate view holders for each and rewrite the code  in both of them....

Answer (score 1):

When you have 2 different layout for recyclerview than you must have 2 different viewholder for it.

First add 2 different viewHolder for your adapter

```
private static int TYPE_SENT = 1;
private static int TYPE_RECEIVED = 2;

private class VideoSentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageSentBinding sentBinding;

    VideoSentHolder(RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageSentBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.sentBinding = binding;
    }
}

private class VideoReceivedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageReceivedBinding receivedBinding;

    VideoReceivedHolder(RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageReceivedBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.receivedBinding = binding;
    }

}
```

after that set item type for adapter with this method

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //Here you have to check condition for sent or received type
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(list.get(position).isSent())) {
        return TYPE_SENT;

    } else {
        return TYPE_RECEIVED;
    }
}
```

in your `onCreateViewHolder` use 2 viewHolder like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_SENT) { // for Sent layout
        RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageSentBinding sentBinding;//Your sent binding
        return new VideoSentHolder(sentBinding);

    } else { // for received layout
        RowRecyclerViewChatVideoMessageReceivedBinding receivedBinding;//=your received binding
        return new VideoReceivedHolder(receivedBinding);
    }
}
```

and inside your onBindViewHolder you can call eash viewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    MessageModel message = values.get(position);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_SENT) {
        ((VideoSentHolder) viewHolder).sentBinding.setMessageModel(message);
    } else {
        ((VideoReceivedHolder) viewHolder).receivedBinding.setMessageModel(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this, but I don't want to rewrite the same bulk load of code in two seprate holders, one should suffice, as It does if you handle the layouts traditionally (without using viewbinding) and having same IDs for it's views.